# Building bidirectional people counting sensor

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, arduino, door-sensor, infrared

I am trying to build a people tracking sensor for counting the traffic of a specific area (building or shopping street). I need to detect people coming in or out of a room, also if two people are walking thorugh an entrance at the same time. 
I would like to use two infrared sensors and need a simple low cost solution.

Requirements:

- entrys up to five meters
- send data to cloud to display in app
- bidirectional
- count multiple people passing

Might there be an already existing solution with code that I can just use for my project? 
Which technology should I use? and which hardware?

Comment: What does "entrys up to five meters" mean?  Also how do you expect it sensors to be able to detect direction?

Comment: if you want to use only two IR sensors, then the sensors would have to be two IR cameras

Comment: Did you make any research? Google yields https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/13/opencv-people-counter/ https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_count_people_in_a_place_through_a_video_camera https://github.com/topics/people-counter ...

Comment: Yes I did make research but there are so many ways and many of them are to complex for me. I also decided now that just counting the people bidirectional is enough, no need to detect multiple people passing. 
It needs to be low cost so maybe an arduino sensor (light barrier) and microcontroller - but how to connect them and make them work? and What cabels to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine two TOF sensors side by side in a corridor. If sensor 1 triggers, then sensor 2, you have movement in one direction. And vice versa.

If you want to check if there are two people, you must have 4 sensors, so you can measure distance for each side of the corridor. Or, you can place the sensors in two opposite sides and count on the person not moving diagonally.

Sending data to the cloud is easily done with and ESP32.

This is as simple and low-cost as I could think. (Good luck finding a suitable sensor though)

Comment: This definitely won’t work for a busy 5 meter wide passageway. An overhead camera with image processing is probably going to be a lot more accurate. Of course it require more processing power, but I’m pretty sure it can still run on pretty cheap hardware.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I am looking for. But I dont know how to connect the devices and what kind of hardware I need to be able to do that..